# Creating a single object of class to be used in other class during library use

Tags: c++

I have a DLL which has a lot of objects doing all sorts of things, and all these objects should have their unique identifying number. Now, I need to implement a class, and one object of this class will generate unique numbers. Unique numbers are needed on object creation (object `file_with_unique_number` in its constructor calls object `generator` and gets a unique number)

When and where in program is it best to create this object? How should all these `file` objects communicate with `generator`? I don't want to pass a pointer to `generator` each time I create a `file`, and from what I've heard using global variables is instant death penalty

Comment: Then why not simply use functions with `static` state? (Not good for thread safety, but anyway.)

Comment: Ah, that seems obvious! I didn't know about static, im still new to c++. So what would be a good way to implement this? Create a `generator` with static variable?

Comment: yes, maybe. But since you need unique numbers, have you looked at [libuuid](http://linux.die.net/man/3/libuuid)?